# How to change foreach::foreach to simple loop in R

Tags: r

I am trying to run this code in R

```
if (bootstrap) {
  mle_new = foreach::foreach(j = 1:nsim, .combine = rbind, 
         .packages = "foreach") %do% zih.mle(sample(x,size = N, replace = T),n= mle_ori[1],alpha1= mle_ori[2],alpha2=mle_ori[3],
                                             type = "zi",lowerbound, upperbound,distr='bb.zihmle')
  mle_new = t(mle_new)
}else {
  mle_new = matrix(rep(mle_ori, nsim), ncol = nsim)
}
```

However, I am getting some error and I want to make this to a simple loop?
Do you have any idea? I appreciate it
Also, can someone please explain what does "::" precisely do in R?

Comment: It would be easier to help if you create a small reproducible example along with expected output. Read about [how to give a reproducible example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269).

Answer (score 0):

`::` is used in R to select the object `foreach` from the package `foreach`. This is often used to prevent namespace clashes.

For example, imagine that you have `package_1` with function `fun`, but also `package_2` with function `fun`. Then the call `fun(...)` is ambiguous and depends on the order of `library(...)` calls. For example:

```
library(package_1)
library(package_2)

fun(...)
```

will call the `fun` function from `package_2`. If you however use `::`, you can  safely call exactly what you want (in this case, `fun` from `package_1`):

```
library(package_1)
library(package_2)

package_1::fun(...)
```

The `fun` needs to be exported, but doesn't have to be loaded. This means that in this case, `library(package_1)` is not required. You should still do the `library` call as this checks if the package is installed.

Similarly to `::`, you can get non-exported objects with the `:::` constructs:

```
package_1:::internal_function(...)
```

This is usually used for functions used by packages that are not exported. These functions are "hidden" and are not exported.

Exported simply means that they are loaded into your namespace when you call `library(...)` and you can then call them directly, i.e., `fun(...)`. You cannot do that with unexported functions and `:::` is the only way to call them.

Comment: Thank you for your detailed explanation. I appreciate your help.